# WMDRM 10 - How can I register/auth a device

Tags: drm

Is there a support in WMDRM10 regarding device registration? how can I prevent spoofing?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no device registration per se in WMDRM 10. However, you do need device certificates. So in principle, if you're writing a client app using (say) PlayReady device porting kit, you could implement a custom scheme whereby you provision the certs online (say, via HTTPS) to the device only if the device itself meets some criteria defined by you (could be, say, a human entering credentials on a webpage).

If these criteria are not met, you won't do the provisioning, and the device is effectively not "registered".